# Electron desktop app file structure

Tags: javascript, path, electron

Can anyone suggest me how file structure works in electron app. The app I have made is working fine if it is not packaged. Once packaged there comes issue with file structure. Can anyone suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 1):

i do not think there's a community blessed structure which can be used.. but generally this is what i follow:

```
- index.html
- package.json
- main.js
- js/
  - app.js
  - some-module.js
- css/
  - style.css
```

source: https://discuss.atom.io/t/file-structure-questions/16484/2
but this might vary depending on requirements for example if you want to ship some additional files to the end-user in your distribution.